# How to reduce shifting line in c language

Tags: c, for-loop

I have long line to configure 14 GPIO pins in intel quark D2000 microcontroller this line written by C language 
the code:

```
cfg.direction = PM[0]<<(TPN[0])|PM[1]<<(TPN[1])|PM[2]<<(TPN[2])|PM[3]<<(TPN[3])|PM[4]<<(TPN[4])|PM[5]<<(TPN[5])|PM[6]<<(TPN[6])|PM[7]<<(TPN[7])|PM[8]<<(TPN[8])|PM[9]<<(TPN[9])|PM[10]<<(TPN[10])|PM[11]<<(TPN[11])|PM[12]<<(TPN[12])|PM[13]<<(TPN[13]);
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code by using "**for loop**"?

Note: "TPN" and "PM" are arrays. "direction" declared as uint8_t variable in the cfg structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible like:

```
int j;
cfg.direction = 0;
for (j=0; j<14; ++j)
{
    cfg.direction |= PM[j]<<TPN[j]);
}
```

If you can't write to `cfg.direction` until you have the final value just use a temp variable:

```
int j;
temp = 0;
for (j=0; j<14; ++j)
{
    temp |= PM[j]<<TPN[j]);
}
cfg.direction = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Thank you, your code working fine for this case but if the case is for only one or two GPIO pins this code not working. I will mark your answer as correct but at first, delete this line "cfg.direction=0" because that mean all the GPIO pins configured as input

Comment: Setting `cfg.direction` to zero first is necessary so that the `|=` operator will work properly (it ORs the current value of `cfg.direction` with the expression on the right and stores the new value back in `cfg.direction`). **IF** setting `cfg.direction` _immediately_ triggers a change to the GPIO, then you'll need to replace both the `cfg.direction`s above with a temporary variable and have `cfg.direction = tempVar` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
cfg.direction = 0;                
for (i=0; i<14; i++)
    cfg.direction |= (PM[i] << TPN[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop to reduce the complexity of the this assignment:

```
uint8_t i=0;
cfg.direction=0;
for(i=0;i<14;i++)
{
  cfg.direction|=PM[i]<<TPN[i];
}
```

so each time the code inside the loop is executed  the value of cfg.direction will be "or bit-wise " with the new GPIO configuration .

At the end of the loop you will find that you get the wanted GPIO configuration for the 14 GPIO Pin.

Comment: there is always a solution:

Answer (score 0):

there is always a solution to make our solution more generic :

```
#define GPIO_PIN_NUMBER 2 // you can change anytime this number 
#define GPIO_DEFAULT_CONFIG ((unit32)0x55555555) // i think this will be output config however you can change it when ever you want

unit8_t=0;
cfg.direction=GPIO_DEFAULT_CONFIG;
for(i=0;i<GPIO_PIN_NUMBER;i++)
{
  cfg.direction|=(PM[i]<<TPN[i]);
}
```